# Spiritual/religious tv series about mystical investigations

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for the tv series which:

- was made after 2000
- probably it was not continued, the number of episodes was small
- English language
- it presents current events

Scenes which I remember:

- the opening episode contains the case where the body in the coffin during exhumation was in really good shape; some people wanted to treat the dead man as saint since then - it occurred that trees in neighborhood (apples or cherries) caused good environment to keep the body preserved
- the meaningful moment of the series shows the car accident (there was no information later on); I remember the car crash with the train and there was a lot of glass

It may happen that I mixed more than one tv show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the TV show [Miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracles_(TV_series)) (a sort of spiritual *X Files* that only lasted 13 episodes) from 2003. The main character's car is hit by a train, and in the [first episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ferguson_Syndrome):

> The series begins at the grave of one Sister Alice Fulton (1834–1861). Workers are exhuming the bodies there in the cemetery, preparing them to be moved before the end of the year. After an accident, Alice's coffin spills open in front of a trapped worker, revealing the corpse of a woman whose eyes are as white as snow, and whose **body has simply not decayed one day since her death over 140 years ago.**

The main character (Skeet Ulrich) suggests that it's because it was buried under an apricot tree, which has preserved her body somehow. Here are the episode's first minutes: